# After failed partition resize, Ubuntu won't boot. It just keeps rebooting again and again

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

So, here's the thing. I was moving a partition with gparted and I stupidly clicked something that crashed the program. Now when I turn on my computer and select ubuntu 12.04 recovery (with linux 3.2.0-41-generic) it fills the screen with text then reboots. I tried with my old linux (3.0.0-12-generic) recovery mode and it filled the screen with text and stopped and did nothing (see screenshot). When I tried Windows XP (I have windows xp dual boot), it just brings up a blank screen with a flashing line. I don't know what to do, I can do a full re-install if I need to but wouldn't prefer to. (sorry about how blurry the screenshot is)

Thanks,

A newbie in need of assistance!!

[image]

Comment: It looks like the `root=` boot option is pointing to an invalid partition, which partition would you like to boot from?

Comment: I want to have an option to boot from either sda6 (ubuntu) or sda1 (windows)

Comment: Try pressing 'e' when you have the Ubuntu boot entry highlighted and find the place where it says `set root=(hdX,Y)` (or similar) and change it to `set root=(hd0,6)` and remove the part which says `UUID=XXXXXXX-YYYYYY`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I also couldn't find exactly what to take out on the UUID option...

Comment: Try deleting the whole `UUID=` option and all the numbers and letters after it UNTIL a space (' '). If there is no UUID option, just leave it and press Ctrl+X to boot

Comment: Boot the livecd and fire gparted back up and check the partitions.  They are probably trashed if you were moving them, but sometimes e2fsck can work miracles.

Comment: and how would i use e2fsck?

Comment: Click on the partition in gparted and choose check.